# Samsung Smart TV App & Brightcove Sample App Remote Control Issue

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control, brightcove

i ran into issues with the Sample App provided by Bightcove (https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Samsung-Smart-TV-Sample-App) for Samsung Smart TV. The remote control does not work on the latest (2012) models. It seems to be a known bug (https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Samsung-Smart-TV-Sample-App/issues/3) and was reportet on github AND in the supports forum on brightcove. Unfortunately they stopped maintaining the sourcecode and no one replies to this issues.

On 2010/2011 models everything works fine.

I think the problem is located somewhere in the enginelite.keyhandler.js:

```
/**
 * 
 *  Simple TV App Engine KeyHandler
 *  
 *  author: A Different Engine LLC.
 *  http://adifferentengine.com
 *  contact@adifferentengine.com
 *
 */
// This is pretty straightforward.
TVEngine.KeyHandler = {

    keyActions:  {
        KEY_UP:             'onUp',
        KEY_DOWN:           'onDown',
        KEY_LEFT:           'onLeft',
        KEY_RIGHT:          'onRight',
        KEY_ENTER:          'onSelect',
        KEY_RETURN:         'onReturn',
        KEY_STOP:           'onStop',
        KEY_FF:             'onFF',
        KEY_RW:             'onRew',
        KEY_PLAY:           'onPlay',
        KEY_PAUSE:          'onPause',
        KEY_YELLOW:         'onYellow',
        KEY_RED:            'onRed',
        KEY_BLUE:           'onBlue',
        KEY_GREEN:          'onGreen',
        KEY_EXIT:           'onExit',
        KEY_MENU:           'onMenu',
        KEY_BACK:           'onReturn',
        KEY_SKIPFFORWARD:   'onSkipForward',
        KEY_SKIPBACK:       'onSkipBack',
    },
    enabled: true,
    keyMap: {},

    init: function() {
        // Maps system key list to ours
        $KEYS = TVEngine.getPlatform().keys();
        // Transforming Samsung keymap into something we like slightly better.
        for(key in $KEYS) {
            this.keyMap[$KEYS[key]] = key;
        }
        this._initializeKeyHandler();
    },
    _cleared: true,
    _initializeKeyHandler: function() {
        var _this = this; var clear;
        $(document).bind("keydown", function(event) {
            var action = _this.keyActions[_this.keyMap[event.keyCode]];
            // $log("<<< GOT KEY ACTION: "+action+">>>");
            if ( action && _this.enabled ) _this.trigger("keyhandler:"+action);
            return false;
        });
        $(document).bind("keyup", function(event) {
            var action = _this.keyActions[_this.keyMap[event.keyCode]]+"Release";
            // $log("<<< GOT KEY ACTION: "+action+" >>>");
            if ( action ) _this.trigger("keyhandler:"+action);
            return false;
        })
    },

    enable: function(){
        this.enabled = true;
    },
    disable: function() {
        this.enabled = false;
    }
};
// Now we can subscribe to the keyhandler from anywhere. 
_.extend(TVEngine.KeyHandler, Backbone.Events);
```

Was someone able to solve this problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `_keys` object in `enginelite.platforms.js` file:

```
this._keys = {
    KEY_RETURN:     88,     //36, //8
    KEY_UP:         29460,  //38,
    KEY_DOWN:       29461,  //40,
    KEY_LEFT:       4,      //37,
    KEY_RIGHT:      5,      //39,
    KEY_ENTER:      29443,  //13,
    KEY_RED:        108,    //65,
    KEY_GREEN:      20,     //66,
    KEY_YELLOW:     21,     //67,
    KEY_BLUE:       22,     //68,
    KEY_BACK:       8,      //I don't know what button on remote it is :)
    KEY_PLAY:       71,     //80,
}
```

And it will work on all Samsung's platforms.

As my answer gives you direct solution the @brimil01 solution gives you the way to debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out the generated keymap to see what keys are being stored in the key handler during init:

```
for(key in $KEYS) {
  alert(key+": "+$KEYS[key]);
  this.keyMap[$KEYS[key]] = key;
}
```

Then capture what keycodes are being sent in the keydown event:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event) {
  alert("keyCode: "+event.keyCode);
  alert("keyMap: "+_this.keyMap[event.keyCode]);
  var action = _this.keyActions[_this.keyMap[event.keyCode]];
  // $log("<<< GOT KEY ACTION: "+action+">>>");
  if ( action && _this.enabled ) _this.trigger("keyhandler:"+action);
  return false;
});
```

This should give you an idea of what is going on in the keyhandler.